# Downgrade the google play services for gcmId gneration for notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-notifications

Previously I was using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

before generating GCMId I am checking play-services

```
/**
 * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
 * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
 * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
 */
public boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {        
            if (AppConstants.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            }
            finish();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am getting gcm error code 2 in 20% devices which means "play-services update is needed in those devices"

    So I decided to downgrade the play-service version to

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
```

but it is giving me error.
     **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
 Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.**

  What should I fix ??
  
Can I generate GCM even if play-service give error code 2(Means even if play-service need update) ??

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found as best combination

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'
```

It is working fine